# Add Foreign Key in Table in ASP.NET MVC in code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to have a one to many relationship in between instructor and course. How can I achieve it? Below is what I have as of now.

```
public class Instructor
{
    //[Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
    //[Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Course")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CSExxx")]
    public string progId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string semester { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public virtual Instructor instructor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This link should get you started with setting up the relationship: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a virtual collection of Course to Instructor

```
public class Instructor
{
    //[Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
    //[Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Course")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CSExxx")]
    public string progId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string semester { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public virtual Instructor instructor { get; set; }
}
```

In OnModelCreating in your DataContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>().HasMany(i => i.Courses).WithRequired(c => c.Instructor).HasForeignKey(c => c.instructor).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Comment: can you please tell which column  is fk?

Comment: I usually configure keys in the OnModelCreating in the DataContext